# How would I go about creating a for loop in SOQL (PHP)

Tags: php, salesforce, soql

I have a simple question.

I'm somewhat new to SOQL and I have a question about it.

I would like to do a select statement in SOQL (that part I get) and have the data display in a while loop.

Would I use a sObject???

I thank you for you help

Comment: Does it have to be a `while`? `for` loops look fairly easy http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_loops_for_SOQL.htm

Comment: Do you mean SQL, or is SOQL a library of some sort?

Comment: SOQL = Salesforce Object Query Language

Answer (score 0):

If your SOQL returns multiple records then that is returned to you via a list, which you can then easily iterate over in your PHP. Do a `print_r()` on the result or your SOQL query to see what I mean.